# What is the "best" Open Source lolcode interpreter?

Tags: lolcode

I'm interested in studying how an interpreter works, and [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.com/) makes me laugh, so: What's the best OpenSource LOLCODE interpeter? Bonus points for providing a decent [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop).

Comment: I'm very disappointed that you didn't write your question in lolcats language

Comment: @Peter: Oh noes! Ur editz haz a grammer fail! "LOLCODE **make** me laugh."

Comment: Actually, writing the question in lolcode seems to be a sure way to get it closed as "not a real question". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435000/i-can-haz-bugfix-closed Moderators haz no meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your favorite/"best-to-understand" language - for example, here's a [Java](http://code.google.com/p/lolcode-java/) and a [Perl](http://drago.cc/lol/) open source interpreter.

Comment: @JB: Thanks for reporting the broken link. Wayback Machine from Internet Archive helps here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090505151552/http://drago.cc/lol/lol.pl

Answer (score 2):

While maybe not the "best" one, I think it's pretty cool that someone from DLR team actually created a [LOLCode interpreter based on the DLR](http://www.iunknown.com/2007/11/lolcode-on-dlr.html), with full access to the .NET Framework.

Added Link from [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20101017154612/http://www.iunknown.com/2007/11/lolcode-on-dlr.html)

Comment: Broken Link Here. Is it still hosted somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

My favorite implementation is [LOLPython](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2007/06/01/lolpython.html)

So, great plus if you're a python fan. :)

And if you wanted to make changes to what's already defined, it's pretty simple. :D

Answer (score 1):

Certainly without a definition of "best", there's little way to answer this question with any certainty. I'm writing an LOLCODE interpreter (http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pllolcode/) to support LOLCODE as a language for writing stored procedures in the PostgreSQL database. (Why, you ask? Because I wanted to learn how.) This interpreter is written in C, and uses Bison and Flex for parsing. These seem to be "best" choices in this case because that's what PostgreSQL itself uses. If you're more familiar with, say, Perl, the Perl-based interpreter is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not an interpreter, but I've used the [Lolcode.net](http://lolcode.com/implementations/lolcode.net) implementation, and it worked rather well for me. It follows the [specifications](http://lolcode.com/specs/1.2) relatively well, except for a few things (like arrays).

Also, I got it to run in Linux using [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)), if Linux compatibility is important to you.