# Which LOLCODE interpreter to use?

Tags: lolcode

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585551/what-is-the-best-open-source-lolcode-interpreter).  What I am asking though, is which [LOLCODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE) interpreter should I pick based on these criteria:

1) Works well and is up-to-date

2) Ease of install - I've looked before and couldn't find one which I found easy to install.

Please feel free to give your suggestions and opinions, I haven't looked in a number of months and am curious as to what people think, and I look forward to learning it.

EDIT: I am just doing this to learn LOLCODE.  Why? Because I can and I think it would be fun to declare variables with ICANHAZ and end programs with KTHXBAI.  I'm really just curious.  I would really prefer that it be as close to spec as possible.  I don't care if it's open or closed source and it can run in either Windows (my desktop) or Linux (my laptop).  Hope this helps!

EDIT 2: I have downloaded the LOLCODE compiler available [here](http://www.iunknown.com/2007/11/lolcode-on-dlr.html).  However, I am having trouble figuring out some of the instructions so I am still open to any suggestions for any other interpreters/compilers.

Answer (score 8):

I highly recommend [repl.it](http://repl.it). It's online, but available for download. It also has other languages like Emoticon, Python, JavaScript and many others. Here's a complete list...

> - Ruby
> - Python
> - Lua
> - Scheme
> - QBasic
> - Forth
> - Javascript
> - Javascript.next
> - Move
> - Kaffeine
> - CoffeeScript
> - Emoticon
> - Brainf***
> - LOLCODE
> - Unlambda
> - Bloop

Unlike the name implies, it has a scripting box right next to the REPL. A perfect setup I believe.

Answer (score 1):

My friend created once LOLCODE interpreter for some project on our Univ. It requires Ruby with some gems, but I don't remember exactly which. I can update answer later when I have time to check it by myself. Here is link to [github repository](http://github.com/qoobaa/lol).